# Box2D: How to get the position of a static body?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, collision-detection, box2d

I have a Box2D world with a mixture of static and dynamic bodies. On collisions, I can only get the positions of the dynamic ones.

Is it possible to get the positions of static objects?

N.b., this is a development of a previous question, [Box2D: How to get the position of a sensor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664928/box2d-how-to-get-the-position-of-a-sensor)

Answer (score 2):

I found a way - in the collision, the center of the AABB will give the position

```
contact.GetFixtureA().GetAABB().GetCenter()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the position vector using the following code:

```
b2Transform t = body->GetTransform();
b2Vec2 pos = b2Vec2(t.p.x,t.p.y);
```

Comment: The above code works on C++, Dunno if it can work on Actionscript too