# Box2D Flash moving one body to another

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, box2d

I am writing a children learning game, whereby you move letter blocks around in physics and snap them in to the correct place.

I have 3 static sensors which work great and when another box touches them I can run code on that instance, but for the life of me I cannot get the moving box to take position of the sensor.

3 days I have tried different ways, with set transform.

All I need to do is move a dynamic box that hits my sensor in to the exact same position as the sensor.

I thought it would be easy but its giving me a real headache...

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems and I found [this](http://www.kerp.net/box2d/) page with a lot of good tutorials, when I learned box2d... Maybe lesson 2.25 and 2.26 point out what you desiring for.

good luck

Comment: SetXForm doesn't seem to be a method I get the error undefined method setxform

Comment: If I remember right than is the guy from the tutorial using the SetLinearVelocity() method to move the body. I have tried it some time ago and it worked fine. I is lesson 2.26 where he explains this

Comment: this has me confused, i want to take a dynamic body and snap it in to place in the exact same place as a static sensor

Comment: http://www.box2dflash.org/docs/2.1a/reference/ there is an SetPosition and SetRotation() method you can also use, but than your body get "beamed" to the new location and collisions are not detected. But than the body does not need to be dynamic, you do not even need physics.

Comment: using the SetPosition i can't get position for sensor body and put them in set position for some reason

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666834/box2d-how-to-get-the-position-of-a-static-body